# how to catch an unhandled exception in windows phone 7 application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, exception, mobile

how to catch an unhandled exception? if all my code wrapped in a `try catch`?
but an exception occurs all the same, and the application crashes ... Maybe there is some general advice?

use:

```
        try
            {
             ...my code
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(),"Error!",MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
```

Sample code is not present, because there is a big code and done many things ... and it looks like somewhere an error occurs, but where it is try-catch does not show, and the application just closes ...

add:

```
var errorw = MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.ToString(), "error", MessageBoxButton.OK); e.Handled = true;
```

And the message: The parameter is incorrect.

Just as we now understand where and what parameter has given is not true? By the way forgot to write that the error occurs when you press Back, when you return to the previous page of the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

would you try like this

```
      // Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender,ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ExceptionObject is QuitException)
        return;

    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }

    //MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.ToString(), "Unexpected error", MessageBoxButton.OK);

    var errorWin = new ErrorWindow(e.ExceptionObject, "An unexpected error has occurred. Please click Send to report the error details.")
                       {Title = "Unexpected Error"};
    errorWin.Show();
    //((PhoneApplicationFrame) RootVisual).Source = new Uri("/Views/ErrorWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

    e.Handled = true;
}

private class QuitException : Exception { }

public static void Quit()
{
    throw new QuitException();
}
```

Comment: And what is ErrorWindow? modified MessageBox?

Comment: put in place ErrorWindow, MessageBox:

var errorw = MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.ToString(), "error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            e.Handled = true;
  
And the message:
The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: Just as we now understand where and what parameter has given is not true? By the way forgot to write that the error occurs when you press Back, when you return to the previous page of the application.

Comment: don't forget:  this.UnhandledException += this.Application_UnhandledException; this being the Application obj.

Comment: This post make more sense when you know that it's code taken from this pretty good blog. The whole error handling is a lot more complicated than indicated. See [link](http://www.geoffhudik.com/tech/2010/10/9/windows-phone-7-error-handling-reporting.html) for a good explanation of how this is used.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a manual.

[UnhandledException event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.unhandledexception%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) description.

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your answer rather than just linking to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `StackTrace` property of `Exception`. It shows you where the exception has been thrown.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace,"Error!",MessageBoxButton.OK);
}
```

Comment: In fact of the matter that does not show. Application immediately closes.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you build application in debug, not release mode. Than, go to VS Debug-Exceptions menu and check all 'Thrown' column to enabled. After that, launch application with attached debugger.
Also, you can execute your code step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys you could use the [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com) library to catch the data and then collect it!
PS. I am one of the founders

Answer (score -2):

Put your code in Try-Catch Block. I was also facing such problem, but then handled by Exception Handling Method.

```
try
 {

   // your code

 }

catch (Exception ex)
 {

   throw (ex);
 }
```

Comment: I think the user is trying to catch exceptions outside your solution. IE all exceptions that did not fall within handled exceptions.